# Unable to replace object in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

Somehow the code below is throwing a **NSInvalidArgumentException**, although I followed step by step to make sure everything has proper value...

I have an array of CGPoints stored in NSValues, and this is part of a method to offset all points by (x,y).

```
for (int i = 0; i < [allPoints count]; i++) {
    CGPoint pt = [[allPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
    CGPoint newPt = CGPointMake(pt.x + x, pt.y + y);
    NSValue *newEntry = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newPt];
    [allPoints replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newEntry];
}
```

Comment: What's the message after NSInvalidArgumentException?

Comment: Only options would appear to be: `i` is somehow out of range, or `newEntry` is somehow nil.

Comment: Where are your x and y variable declared? And what is their type?

Comment: 2013-08-01 23:09:39.430 [39499:c07] -[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8868240
2013-08-01 23:09:39.432 Draw A Graph![39499:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8868240'


i is 0 and newEntry has proper value.

Comment: That's not an NSMutableArray, it's an NSArray.

Comment: Can you show where allPoints is declared or probably last set?

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

-----------------------------sample code---------------------------------

```
CGPoint pt =CGPointMake(20, 30);
NSValue *point = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt];

CGPoint pt2 =CGPointMake(40, 40);
NSValue *point2 = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt2];

NSMutableArray *allPoints =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:point,point2, nil];
NSLog(@"%@",allPoints);
// -------------output----------
//     "NSPoint: {20, 30}",
//     "NSPoint: {40, 40}"
int x=10; int y=20;
for (int i = 0; i < [allPoints count]; i++)
{
    CGPoint pt = [[allPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
    CGPoint newPt = CGPointMake(pt.x + x, pt.y + y);
    NSValue *newEntry = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newPt];
    [allPoints replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newEntry];
}
NSLog(@"%@",allPoints);
// -------------output----------
//     "NSPoint: {30, 50}",
//     "NSPoint: {50, 60}"
```

Comment: I tried that and it works perfectly, but as soon as I replace the array with the one in my program it crashes. Must be something about the array but I cannot figure out what. NSLog outputs a list of NSPoints and they are all fine.

Comment: can you show NSMutableArray all objects .Double check if one of objects in allPoints NSMutableArray is nil

Answer (score 0):

NSMutableArray method replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if object at given index is nil or new object is nil.
Double check if one of objects in allPoints NSMutableArray is nil.

Or allPoints NSMutableArray doesn't contain NSValue objects with CGPoint elements.

Comment: Well if the points in NSMutableArray doesn't contain NSValue objects with CGPoint elements then it will throw an exception at 
        CGPoint pt = [[allPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue]; already.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how, but it seems although I declared allPoints to be **NSMutableArray** and after a search in my entire code I cannot find in any place where I set the pointer of allPoints to a **NSArray**, but the system seems to think now that allPoints is now a **NSArray** and hence I cannot replace any objects.

Therefore I have to circumvent with a new NSMutableArray.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [allPoints count]; i++) {
    CGPoint pt = [[allPoints objectAtIndex:i] CGPointValue];
    CGPoint newPt = CGPointMake(pt.x + x, pt.y + y);
    NSValue *newEntry = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:newPt];
    NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:allPoints];
    [temp replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newEntry];
    allPoints = temp;
}
```

Comment: That's super inefficient.  You don't want to re-allocate your array every time through the loop.  Convert `allPoints` to NSMutableArray before your loop.

Comment: Do you perhaps get the NSMutableArray from a property set to "copy"? Have done that myself many times, a copy of an NSMutableArray is an NSArray.

Comment: Hmm, that must be it! I definitely did use copy somewhere!

Right, it was in my custom object's copyWithZone: where I put copy.allPoints = [self.allPoints copy]; I now replaced it with copy.allPoints = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.allPoints]; and it works perfectly!